# wordpress site: Apache redirect URI path

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, redirect

We have a wordpress site http://10.10.10.10/sitename/.

When the user enters a "string" in the search bar and hits enter, the request is sent to http://10.10.10.10/?s= and is thrown the default Apache index.html.

Expected behavior: The user should be sent to http://10.10.10.10/sitename/?s= instead of http://10.10.10.10/?s=

What are the possible ways to implement a redirect from /?s= to /sitename/?s=

Thank you,

Comment: Check that your wordpress options are correct, especially the wordpress and website URL options from `http://10.10.10.10/sitename/wp-admin/options-general.php` (they are probably set to `http://10.10.10.10/` instead of `http://10.10.10.10/sitename/`)

Comment: @Capsule : Both WordPress Address URL & Site Address URL are set to http://10.10.10.10/sitename.

Comment: Did you try to use another theme? The one you use might have the search URL hardcoded to the domain root. That would be a very bad idea but who knows.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use the wp_redirect() function of the wordpress

```
$url ="http://10.10.10.10/sitename/?s=";
    wp_redirect($url);
```

here is the [wordpress documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/) page of this function

Comment: And you intend to put that outside of the wordpress folder as an ugly patch that won't even work?